# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, typeerror, angular-cli, google-developers-console, google-developer-tools

There is an error in this part of my code

```
<img src="../../../assets/gms-logo.png" alt="logo" routerLink="/overview" alt="website icon">
```

But when I checked the assets folder, `gms-logo.png` is still there and in `angular-cli.json`, assets is also there. The path is also correct.

Recently though, I've been working on Search function. So my hypothesis is,

> Has the program started searching even if the user is still not focused on the input type? How do I fix this?

Below is my html for Search and the showing of its suggestion segment

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" (keyup)="onSearch($event.target.value)">        
<div class="suggestion"  *ngIf="results.length > 0">
     <div *ngFor="let result of results ">
          <a href="" target="_blank">
                {{ result.name }}
          </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Below is my component

```
results: Object;



 onSearch(name) {
            this.search
            .searchEmployee(name)
            .subscribe(
                name => this.results = name,//alert(searchName),this.route.navigate(['/information/employees/']),
                error => alert(error),
                );
}
```

Comment: you can access your img like this "assets/gms-logo.png"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to initialize your `results` variable as an array.

In your component, add:

```
results = [];
```

Another option is to change your suggestion div's `*ngIf` statement to check if `results` is defined:

```
<div class="suggestion"  *ngIf="results">
   <div *ngFor="let result of results ">
          <a href="" target="_blank">
                {{ result.name }}
       </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've set result into an object. That's why. Thanks

Comment: No problem - keep at it!

Comment: Another option: `results?.length > 0`.

Comment: @developer033 Was looking everywhere for the fix since other solutions didnt work for Observable object array. But "?." fixed it instantly! Thanks a ton!

Comment: I added  private userListing: User[]=[]; and then working. Thanks

Comment: We may simply use `*ngif="results?.length"`

Answer (score 13):

[The safe navigation operator ( ?. ) and null property paths](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)

> The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a fluent and convenient way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths. Here it is, protecting against a view render failure if the currentHero is null.

So in your example you can also use *The safe navigation operator ( ?. )*:

```
<div class="suggestion"  *ngIf="results?.length > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let result of results ">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
            {{ result.name }}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Initializing the variable to empty solved my issue.

```
 DoctorList: any[] = [];
```

Answer (score 4):

I got stuck in a similar situation where even after assigning `results` as an *array* *( as shown below )*, the error persisted.

```
results: Array<any>;
```

Using '?' *( Safe Navigation Operator )* worked out well for me.

```
*ngIf="results?.length"
```

The **Safe Navigation Operator** (?) can be used to prevent Angular from throwing errors while trying to access the properties of an object that doesn't exist.

This example will evaluate the `length` only when a value of `results` is not *Null* or *Undefined*.

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue. I found 2 ways to fix it

1. Assign result as an Array

   result = []

in html

```
*ngIf="results.length"
```

2. Use ?

   *ngIf="results?.length"

Answer (score 0):

you can just initialise your array in declaration :

```
    result: Array<any>;
```

if the probleme style persiste you should check of null in your  method lik this :

```
onSearch(name) {
        this.search
        .searchEmployee(name)
        .subscribe(
            name =>
if(name!=null){
this.results = 
name,//alert(searchName),this.route.navigate(['/information/employees/']),
}

            error => alert(error),
            );
}
```